# Google play console clear data of tester trial use

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I use the test track and have added my email to the tester list. Everything works fine, tested the subscription, then the trial. But since the trial lasted 3 minutes I didn't have time to test everything, and I couldn't find a feature to allow testers to use the trial again.

Do I really need to create a new account every time I want to get the trial for those minutes of testing?

I tried clearing the purchase history on my phone and looking for more information about app testing, but all I found was the same question.